# How do I enable short key to wrap with widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to Wrap with widget to Column in body.

I've read that there is a short key to see options for that(option + enter)(I use MacBook IOS)
People say that many options will pop up with PopUpMenu.But when I do that, only option I can see is "Adjust code style setting".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Windows --> **Alt+Enter**

PopUpMenu will displayed on selected widget

[image]

Answer (score 0):

click on the widget and press **ctrl + '.'**

you will get multiple options to wrap the widget.

[screenshot showing the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUPnX.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac it works with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

In Dart you can also click on the lightbulb to show wrapping options.

Here are more shortcuts:

- Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts
- Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf